# how to get each key and value from object in javascript for high chart graph

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, object, highcharts

I am getting this kind of object(hash) form rails:-

```
foo = {"a"=>[0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0, 8, 7, 5, 4, 9, .....],
"b"=>[0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ......],  
"c"=>[ 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0, 8, 7, 5, 4, 9, 0, 0, .......]}
```

My high chart graph js is:-

```
$(function() {
 if ($("#graph").length > 0){
 var download_chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    renderTo: 'graph'
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    enabled: true
  },
  navigator: {
    enabled: false
  },
  title: {
    text: ' '
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
    align: 'top',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    borderWidth: 0
  },
  credits: {
    enabled : false
  },
  series: [{
      name: '...',
      data: foo
    }],
  });
 }
});
```

I want to draw **[Basic Area high chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-basic)** that refer *name as "a"* and their *key [5,4,9,..] is data* in `series` of high chart javascript so for multiple key and values it will show different marked area. All keys and values i can directly pass from rails but then graph will draw single area for all keys that is wrong.

so where should i implement `foo` to get each *key* as a name and their *values of Array[]* as data to generate different Areas in graph.

Comment: jsonParse, ParseJson is not working and basic area high chart is need this kind of structure - `series: [{name: 'USA',
                       data: [null, 27387, 2945]}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would basically do this on the server side:

```
series = foo.map{ |k, v| { name: k, data: v } }
```

And take a look at [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) or [highcharts_on_rails](https://github.com/stevo/highcharts_on_rails) gems. Both are really neat for working with Highcharts.